# problems with splitting line using tab delimiter

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm reading in input from a file in the following form:

```
a b c d e
```

where the alphabets each represent a string and are separated by the `tab` character. I am using a bufferedreader to read the line and splitting it using:

```
String[] splitString= currentLine.split("\t");
```

where `currentLine` is a string that contains the line read by the bufferedreader.

HOWEVER, there can be certain instances in the input where either `b` could be blank or `e` could be blank (refer to example input above).

What I want to be able to do is carry out a different operation for each of these instances as follows:

```
if (b is blank){
do this
}else if (e is blank) {
do this
}else{
do this
}
```

However I can't come up with a suitable if condition that would accurately achieve this functionality

Any suggestions are welcome

EDIT:

This is the normal form of the input provided that nothing is "blank"

```
a[tab]b[tab]c[tab]d[tab]e
```

Lets say that whatever was supposed to be in the position of `b` is now blank, the input would look like this:

```
a[tab][tab]c[tab]d[tab]e
```

Comment: What does it mean that b could be blank? Are you reading the input as `abcde` (no spaces) and then when b is blank you're reading `acde`, or are you reading it with spaces and then b is blank when you're reading `a c d e`? What does 'blank' mean in your question?

Comment: If you have `x y z`, how do you know that either `b` or `e` is blank, or `a` and `d` are etc? There are many possibilities

Comment: I have edited the OP to better explain @OriLentz

Comment: @fge what do you mean? Does my edit answer your question?

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I've answered below. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split according to tabs (using `\\t` - meaning only tabs to split). An empty string will indicate you had two tabs in a row.

```
string.split("\\t");
```

Example:

```
String str = "hello[tab]hi[tab]how are you?"
String[] arr = str.split("\\t");
```

Will result in an array of size 3 with the elements: `hello, hi, how are you?`

However, for `String str = "hello[tab][tab]hi[tab][tab][tab]how are you?"`, the result will be an array of size 6 with the elements `hello, , hi, , , how are you?"`

Simply check where you have "empty strings" and they'll tell you what's missing where.

Comment: are you sure that the resulting array would be of size 6? Because I'm pretty sure I tried something similar to this and it didn't end up working

Comment: never mind I just checked and its allgood, however, to check for empty strings would you just have to check for the null character?

Comment: just check for either null or the more preferred .isEmpty()

Answer (score 1):

You can try with :

```
String[] splitString = currentLine.split("\\s");
```

The regex `\\s` matches single whitespace character.

A whitespace character consists of  `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand that but I want to be able to differentiate between the two scenarios. If `b` is blank then I want to do something, and similar when `e` is blank

Comment: What will be stored in the element corresponding to the blank space in the splitString array?

Comment: if my input was `a   c d e` then what would the splitString array contain based off your code above?